# Firebase Cloud Function Too Slow

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that receives the uid of an image and associate it to the user who calls it after validating its dimensions and generate its thumbnail. It looks simple but I have to wait around 40 seconds to see the results, and sometimes it gets congested or something and I have to call the function again to see previous results.

Has anyone experience it before? How can I fix that?

```
exports.validateImageDimensions = functions
  .region("us-central1")
  .runWith({ memory: "2GB", timeoutSeconds: 120 })
  .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
```

As you can see the CPU used is high...

Thanks.

### UPDATE

Code of the function:

```
exports.validateImageDimensions = functions
  .region("us-central1")
  .runWith({ memory: "2GB", timeoutSeconds: 120 })
  .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    // Libraries
    const admin = require("firebase-admin");
    const sizeOf = require("image-size");
    const url = require("url");
    const https = require("https");
    const sharp = require("sharp");
    const path = require("path");
    const os = require("os");
    const fs = require("fs");

    // Lazy initialization of the Admin SDK
    if (!is_validateImageDimensions_initialized) {
      admin.initializeApp();
      is_validateImageDimensions_initialized = true;
    }

    // Create Storage
    const storage = admin.storage();

    // Create Firestore
    const firestore = admin.firestore();

    // Get the image's owner
    const owner = context.auth.token.uid;

    // Get the image's info
    const { id, description, location, tags } = data;

    // Photos's bucket
    const bucket = storage.bucket("bucket");

    // File Path
    const filePath = `photos/${id}`;

    // Get the file
    const file = getFile(filePath);

    // Check if the file is a jpeg image
    const metadata = await file.getMetadata();
    const isJpgImage = metadata[0].contentType === "image/jpeg";

    // Get the file's url
    const fileUrl = await getUrl(file);

    // Get the photo dimensions using the `image-size` library
    https.get(url.parse(fileUrl), (response) => {
      let chunks = [];
      response
        .on("data", (chunk) => {
          chunks.push(chunk);
        })
        .on("end", async () => {
          // Check if the image has valid dimensions
          let dimensions = sizeOf(Buffer.concat(chunks));

          // Create the associated Firestore's document to the valid images
          if (isJpgImage && hasValidDimensions(dimensions)) {
            // Create a thumbnail for the uploaded image
            const thumbnailPath = await generateThumbnail(filePath);

            // Get the thumbnail
            const thumbnail = getFile(thumbnailPath);

            // Get the thumbnail's url
            const thumbnailUrl = await getUrl(thumbnail);

            try {
              await firestore
                .collection("posts")
                .doc(owner)
                .collection("userPosts")
                .add({
                  id,
                  uri: fileUrl,
                  thumbnailUri: thumbnailUrl, // Useful for progress images
                  description,
                  location,
                  tags,
                  date: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                  likes: [], // At the first time, when a post is created, zero users has liked it
                  comments: [], // Also, there aren't any comments
                  width: dimensions.width,
                  height: dimensions.height,
                });

              // TODO: Analytics posts counter
            } catch (err) {
              console.error(
                `Error creating the document in 'posts/{owner}/userPosts/' where 'id === ${id}': ${err}`
              );
            }
          } else {
            // Remove the files that are not jpeg images, or whose dimensions are not valid
            try {
              await file.delete();

              console.log(
                `The image '${id}' has been deleted because it has invalid dimensions.
                 This may be an attempt to break the security of the app made by the user '${owner}'`
              );
            } catch (err) {
              console.error(`Error deleting invalid file '${id}': ${err}`);
            }
          }
        });
    });

    /* ---------------- AUXILIAR FUNCTIONS  ---------------- */

    function getFile(filePath) {
      /* Get a file from the storage bucket */

      return bucket.file(filePath);
    }

    async function getUrl(file) {
      /* Get the public url of a file  */

      const signedUrls = await file.getSignedUrl({
        action: "read",
        expires: "01-01-2100",
      });

      // signedUrls[0] contains the file's public URL
      return signedUrls[0];
    }

    function hasValidDimensions(dimensions) {
      // Posts' valid dimensions
      const validDimensions = [
        {
          width: 1080,
          height: 1080,
        },
        {
          width: 1080,
          height: 1350,
        },
        {
          width: 1080,
          height: 750,
        },
      ];

      return (
        validDimensions.find(
          ({ width, height }) =>
            width === dimensions.width && height === dimensions.height
        ) !== undefined
      );
    }

    async function generateThumbnail(filePath) {
      /* Generate thumbnail for the progressive images */

      // Download file from bucket
      const fileName = filePath.split("/").pop();
      const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName);

      const thumbnailPath = await bucket
        .file(filePath)
        .download({
          destination: tempFilePath,
        })
        .then(() => {
          // Generate a thumbnail using Sharp
          const size = 50;
          const newFileName = `${fileName}_${size}_thumb.jpg`;
          const newFilePath = `thumbnails/${newFileName}`;
          const newFileTemp = path.join(os.tmpdir(), newFileName);
          sharp(tempFilePath)
            .resize(size, null)
            .toFile(newFileTemp, async (_err, info) => {
              // Uploading the thumbnail.
              await bucket.upload(newFileTemp, {
                destination: newFilePath,
              });

              // Once the thumbnail has been uploaded delete the temporal file to free up disk space.
              fs.unlinkSync(tempFilePath);
            });

          // Return the thumbnail's path
          return newFilePath;
        });

      return thumbnailPath;
    }
  });
```

Pd: In the console I can read this record:

```
"Function execution took 103 ms, finished with status code: 200"
```

but I have to wait, as I said before, around 40 seconds to see the new doc on my firestore

Comment: It's hard to answer your question without seeing the actual function maybe it's not efficient which causes long wait time. Also your cloud function runs with 2GB of RAM, it's not CPU.

Comment: I read that in the function configuration that if I set a higher RAM the function will also have more CPU.

Comment: @Yos I have updated the question with the full code.

Comment: maybe it has to do with some delay in firestore. if you create a test object with hardcoded values does it also take 40 seconds to show up?

Comment: Have found that the problem is with: https.get(url.parse(fileUrl), (response) => {
      let chunks = [];
      response
        .on("data", (chunk) => {
          chunks.push(chunk);
        })
        .on("end", async () => { ....   If I upload the image association before it to the firestore I can see the result in 1 sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not dealing with promises correctly.  A callable function must return a promise that:

1. Resolves when all of the async work is complete
2. Resolves with the data to send back to the client

Right now, your function returns nothing, so it returns to the caller immediately, and the future of the async work that you kicked off is uncertain.

Note that [`https.get()`](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback) is asynchronous and returns immediately, before its callback is invoked.  You will need to find a way to instead return a promise that resovles when all of the callback's work is complete.  (Consider that there are other HTTP client libraries that make it easier to get a promise instead of having to deal with callbacks.)

Comment: Should I return void? I mean, in the client I don't expect to get a response from the function, I used https.onCall because I thought that was a way to call a cloud function from the app

Comment: The client is expecting a response regardless of whether or not you need to send one.  That's how HTTP works.  Return a promise that resolves with the data to send, or at least some dummy data, like an empty object.  That promise must only resolve after all the async work is fully complete, or that async work will not behave the way you expect.

Comment: Man you are a genius just do exactly what you said and getting the result in one sec. Thanks a lot man!!! Hopefully someday will be as professional in javascript as you :D